# How to use flex in react-native correctly?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react application. In there I have created a page header in my app which is common to all my components and the title of the Header will be change accordingly.

This image shows what my code does.

[image]

What I want to achieve is this.

[image]

This is my code of that Page header.

/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Image} from 'react-native';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

class PageHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{zIndex: 0}}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#fdc830', '#ff9a00']}
          style={{alignItems: 'center', borderBottomLeftRadius: 80}}>
          <View
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: '10%',
              marginBottom: '5%',
              paddingTop: '5%',
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontStyle: 'normal',
                fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                letterSpacing: 0.81,
                color: '#000104',
                marginTop: '2%',
                marginLeft: this.props.marginLeft,
                marginRight: '2%',
              }}>
              {this.props.title}
            </Text>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 10,
                marginTop: this.props.marginTop,
              }}
              source={this.props.image}
            />
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    flex: 3,
  },
  homeHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
  },
  homeHeaderImage: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    letterSpacing: 0.81,
    color: '#000104',
    marginTop: '2%',
    marginLeft: '30%',
    marginRight: '3%',
  },
  hederContentContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: '30%',
    marginBottom: '10%',
  },
  qrCodeGeneraterContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  viewDetails: {
    color: '#ff9a00',
    fontSize: 12,
    marginLeft: '75%',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: '2%',
    marginBottom: '1%',
  },
});

export default PageHeader;
```

This is how I am using this component in my home component.

```
 <PageHeader
          title="Settings"
          image={require('../../../assets/settings.png')}
          width={DEVICE_WIDTH / 14}
          height={DEVICE_HEIGHT / 24}
          marginTop="2%"
          marginLeft="40%"
        />
```

What wrong with my code is it not showing the image fully. I tried so many ways to get the image full but I was unable to do so. And It shows different difference sizes on different device sizes as I have given the width based on the device with. Can someone help me to solve these two issues? Thank you.

Comment: can you explain more clearly and share oyur code in an expo snack so that we can check there and revert

Comment: @GauravRoy I update the question with an image which shows what I need to achieve

Comment: @Tim I updated a question with an image that explains what I need to achieve. The first image shows how my code make the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your image component :

```
<Image
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                marginTop: this.props.marginTop,
                resizeMode="contain"
              }}
              source={this.props.image}
            />
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts